# Virtualbox + shared folder gives protocol error for user with group access vboxsf

Tags: git, virtualbox, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-server

I have installed virtualbox Ubuntu 16.04 LTS - 64bit server on my windows 10 machine.
Installation went just fine. 
However, now I am trying to get git clone from my existing repo to the shared folder "sf_Users" in this case, it keeps on giving error as

```
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'application': Protocol error

My VM settings -> shared folders -> machine folder says => Users C:/Users/app-dev
 -- auto-mount = Yes -- Access = Full
```

from terminal my id shows up access to group vboxsf

```
dev@app-dev:/media/sf_Users$ id
uid=1000(dev) gid=1000(dev) groups=1000(dev),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),110(lxd),119(libvirtd),120(lpadmin),121(sambashare),125(vboxsf)
dev@app-dev:/media/sf_Users$ cd ..
dev@app-dev:/media$ ls -al
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root   4096 Nov 29  2016 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root   4096 Nov 29 10:04 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Nov 29 09:59 cdrom
drwxrwx---  1 root vboxsf    0 Nov 28 09:20 sf_Users
```

from "id" command, I know that I have access to vboxsf. Am i missing something more?

Comment: Well, I solved it myself

Answer (score 2):

I gave write permissions to shared folder on windows machine (in my case it was C:/Users/app-dev). restarted the windows machine (this is a must) and then was able to write to sf_Users on VM.

Answer (score 1):

This image is the error I received

[image: img_received]

I tried Compressing the folder/file that caused the problem by ".7z" , then I copied and opened it on my windows host machine, it worked for me. Phew, The files were copied without leaving them out.

What did I see ?

[image: img_see]

Well i didn't care much less, i renamed it.

(This comment is only a quick post of what i resolved myself with no time to dig in)